# Display blockquote of text in article post, while showing original

Tags: 7, theming, wysiwyg

Can anyone provide an idea for how I can add a block quote in an article post where that text is also in the body of the message?

What I mean by this, is that right now when one of our users wants to create a blockquote, they use the CKeditor WYSIWYG module and choose 'blockquote'. What this does is highlight that specific text as a blockquote. What I am more looking for is the ability of the writer to choose what they would like to have as a blockquote and also see that same text again where it belongs in the article.  Please see the image below for what I mean.

Ideally it would be great to have certain text highlighted that it is a blockquote. Then have that blockquote be right next to the original.

[image]

Update: I just talked with our themer and maybe the best solution is to highlight any text that we want blockquoted and include it in there twice. Then we can style the text with CSS that has the blockquote tag. But if there is a better way, then great!

Comment: you could create a preprocessor that extracted the text within a square bracket for example and then applied some CSS styling to it. for example [this will be a quote]

Comment: @AndrewWelch That's actually a good idea. Can you help in any way with the preprocessor? I am not that well versed with Drupal PHP for that.

Comment: you would have to do a preprocess on the body field and then use regex to replace whats in the square brackets. However, I think the CSS option also seems nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the block quote using the blockquote {} tag in CSS.

For example, something similar to the image you uploaded...

```
blockquote {
float:left;
margin:20px;
font-size:1.2em;
color:red;
}
```

However, your client would need to enter the piece of text twice.

Comment: I agree that this would be the easiest on my end, but might be a bit complicated for the client. I'm going to see if any other ideas pop up. Thanks!